# Do I need 14 different layouts to support all Android devices?

Tags: android, screen, resolution, android-screen-support

I'm really feeling confused.  From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) at developer.android.com, it seems in order to keep my images scaled correctly (aspect ratio too) across all current Android devices I need all these layouts below.  Is that really what everyone is doing?  Am I missing something, or should I be going about this a different way?

> ```
> Low density Small screens QVGA 240x320
> ------------------------------------------------
> layout-small-ldpi
> layout-small-land-ldpi
>
> Low density Normal screens WVGA400 240x400 (x432)
> ------------------------------------------------
> layout-ldpi
> layout-land-ldpi
>
> Medium density Normal screens HVGA 320x480
> ------------------------------------------------
> layout-mdpi
> layout-land-mdpi
>
> Medium density Large screens HVGA 320x480
> ------------------------------------------------
> layout-large-mdpi
> layout-large-land-mdpi
>
> High density Normal screens WVGA800 480x800 (x854)
> ------------------------------------------------
> layout-hdpi
> layout-land-hdpi
>
> Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res)
> ------------------------------------------------
> layout-xlarge
> layout-xlarge-land
> ```

Comment: No you don't need to, i have implemented my own way of handling multiple screen resolutions, refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16518557/1939564

Comment: That's certainly an innovative approach! Part of the reason for the multiple layout capability however is to also enable the developer to use screen resources differently depending on what device or orientation the application is running on. I think it's only fair to point out that iOS uses the exact same method. There is Storyboard (layout) for iPad as well as iPhone devices. You must maintain both if you want a cross-device application. .

Comment: @wufoo I really appreaciate your table. Is there a possibility to get also numbers for newer screens (they got bigger, like xxlarge,..) ?
Or if you can reffer me a link to it, I'd apprecaite it!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your app will work on 100% of the devices with the classic layout.

You can just add some buttons or change the layout in landscape mode by adding some qualifiers but that's up to you!

For instance, on LDPI (small resolution) device, you may want to adjust some buttons or change a little bit to fit the small screen.

You may also want to put some buttons on the right in landscape mode and in the bottom of your layout in portrait!

You do not "have to" use them.

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm having trouble with specifically are image backgrounds.  My company wants to put up a splash-screen when the application starts and it really scales weird depending on the orientation of the device.  I fixed that by making two splash-sceen images; one portrait, one landscape however the problem now is when I run the app on the Xoom, the splash-screen is all blurry and jaggy.  If I scale a Xoom resolution splash-screen down to a QVGA emulator, the text becomes unreadable.  So, do I make a different res splash-screen for every device, or is there a happy medium somewhere?

Comment: You just need to add a different image/layout in xlarge and/or xlarge-land then the xoom (and other xlarge screen devices) will use those, and all others will look at the normal ones.

Comment: mixing the meaning of ldpi and small terms leads to this confusion.. 
Check http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html under section Using configuration qualifiers
small, normal, large, xlarge should be used for providing different layouts.. 
ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi should be used to provide different image sizes.. Just my opinion...

Comment: I have different layouts for each, but still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app

Answer (score 8):

**According to Android Dev [Protip](https://plus.google.com/108967384991768947849/posts/2CpwdBJ8e6B) from Roman Nurik  about screen size qualifiers:**

> If you have custom layouts for larger screen devices such as tablets,
>   now's the time to stop using the **-large or -xlarge** resource qualifier
>   and switch to using **-swXXdp or -wXXdp** qualifiers. The latter were
>   introduced in **API level 13**, which basically all tablets now have
>   support for according to the latest platform version charts1.
>
> means that for basically all cases where -large would have any effect,
>   **-swXXdp** can be used instead to provide more granularity.
>
> So which actual **sw or w** qualifiers should you use? Here's a quick
>   just-give-me-something starting point:
>
> **7" tablets: Instead of layout-large, use layout-sw600dp.**
>
> Example: Nexus 7 = 960×600 dp; the smaller of the two dimensions is
>   600.
>
> **10" tablets: Instead of layout-xlarge, use layout-sw720dp.**
>
> Example: Nexus 10 = 1280×800 dp; the smaller of the two dimensions is
>   800. Some 10" tablets are a bit more narrow so 720 is a commonly used switching point.
>
> There's more to it than just that (you really want to choose switching
>   points based on your content's minimum requirements, not on device
>   form factor), but that's a #Protip for another day (::cough:: +Nick
>   Butcher ::cough::).

Comment: what about kindle HD 7 ? it's under sw530dp and Samsung Tab 7 can't identify "sw" qualifier as it has 2.3 and in my app minimum SDK is 8.

Comment: @VishalKhakhkhar almost my hair started becoming gray!! read this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156157/nexus-7-and-kindle-fire-hd-think-different

Comment: Yes that's true.. that means it is must to implement large for Old Samsung Tab 7 and sw530 common for Kindle 7 and Nexus 7 right ?

Comment: and about XLarge.. Xoom devices with OS 3.0 can't get layout from sw720. So must have to add Xlarge too.. any other solution ?

Comment: This seems to read that supporting devices from 2.3.7 on up, it will require using even more layouts. yikes!

Comment: How do we change the orientation of the layout file using sw qualifiers.

Answer (score 2):

In the layout if you do not use AbsoluteLayout, you application is going to be resized to fit the screen.

But in some cases, for smaller screens you need declare a new layout with less components for example.

For images:

You has some options.

Simple ignore some resolutions and let the device choose the best image to it.
Declare on AndroidManifest for wich sizes you want to support.
Or has just one and let the resize screw your application.

Comment: I have different layouts for each, but still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should define different layout for different screen resolution.

When you are supposed to work with tablet kind of application. That time really you feel that. There is a need of different layout. Because Tablets always comes in different size.

One more thing, When you are working on android, means you should always taste your app with real device. And also test with different size emulators.