# multiple screen support in android

Tags: android, resolution

I am working on a project and i have tested it on nexus one. its working there properly but I want that my project should be compatible with all screen sizes.
How to do this??
I have given

```
<supports-screens  android:smallScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens  android:normalScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

parameters in the androidmainfest.xml

Comment: Please check Below Link . 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/5558534/562296

Comment: you should first consider googlong yourself, there is a wealth of information on this topic including the android dc docs!

Comment: I have different layouts for each, but still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You have to add different folder for different layout in res folder --> hdpi,mdpi,ldpi and for large screens you xhdpi(for Tablet) and large-hdpi or xlarge (for NXzoom). Also set Images and text size different in different layout as per screensize...

Comment: thats i already said....change your images size according to screen size you get also screensize programmatically and Put UI .........

Comment: can you give me some example how to do this

Comment: I have different layouts for each, but still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app

Answer (score 3):

For Old day, we used to create different layout folder such as layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge for multiple screen. But that is a hell lot of work. So there is a new way to support multiple screen. Details are given below.

**For Support Multiple Screen (All Mobiles and Tablets):**

**For Mobiles** : We generally using different values folders for different dpi and inside that values folders only the “dimens.xml” file is different because when we are using different devices only the dimension is changed other than that all the parameters for example colors, strings, styles etc. are same.
For values folders: There are total 4 values folders.

```
values                                    (For mdpi devices)
values-hdpi                               (For hdpi devices)
values-xhdpi                              (For xhdpi devices)
values-xxhdpi                             (For xxhdpi devices)
```

(here Inside each folder only dimens file is different so except dimens file, keep all other files only in values folder.)

**For Tablets** : We have to use sw (smallestWidth) concept. For example sw600dp means the system will use these resources only when the smallest dimension of available screen is at least 600dp. The device’s smallestWidth does not change when the screen’s orientation changes.
Generally we create two folders inside res folder for tablets:

```
layout-sw600dp                       (For 7″ to 9″ Screen)
layout-sw720dp                       (For 10″ to above screen)
```

One last thing, Images for any device (Mobiles or Tablets) you have to create different drawable folders:

```
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

Comment: Please don't copy and paste the same answer to lots of questions. You can either give each question the individual answer it deserves, or write one canonical answer and flag the rest of the questions as duplicates if they really are duplicates.

Comment: I have different layouts for each, but still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app

Answer (score 0):

i am dealing with it this way and its working fine.....if any one has improved wayso do guide me

**Screen size 480x800**

layout-normal-hdpi-480x800

drawable-normal-hdpi-480x800

Screen size **Galaxy Nexus**--- though its size is 1280x720 but in actual due to system bar its dimension(screen size) differs

layout-normal-xhdpi

drawable-normal-xhdpi

Screen size **Note 5.3**---

layout-normal-xhdpi-1280x800

drawable-normal-xhdpi-1280x800

Screen size **S3**---

layout-normal-xhdpi-1280x720

drawable-normal-xhdpi-1280x720

Screen size **7inch tab 2** supporting OS version 3 and above--- dont write dimension 1026x600 bsz in actual due to system bar its dimension(screen size) differs

layout-large-mdpi

drawable-large-mdpi

Screen size **7inch tab p1000** etc supoorting os verion less than 3---

layout-large-hdpi-1024x600

drawable-large-hdpi-1024x600

Screen size **1280x800** tab 10.1,10.2,note 10.1 etc--- you can add dimension if you want other wise it is fine

layout-xlarge-mdpi

drawable-xlarge-mdpi

Comment: I have different layouts for each, but still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are great in there own means.Many times we're in scenario where our nested `LinearLayout` within `RelativeLayout` is hard to fit all the screens considering some complex layout line `Tile`

The above scenario can be solved by android's percent support library fitting all the screens.

[Demo HERE](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)

[GitHub Project HERE](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ff7acfff"
        android:text="20% - 50%"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:text="80%-50%"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

[image: Simple example for demo]

Hope anyone find it useful :-).

Comment: I have different layouts for each, but still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app