# Supporting one apk for multiple screens for tablet and mobile screen

Tags: android

I have creaated one application for mobile and same for tablate screen using layout-h600dp custom layout file to run same .apk file on tablet.But i have faced one problem.Screen showing on the tablet was not coming completely.

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/7453982/1021695

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 layouts in your application

- **res->layout** => this will be normal mobile screens
- **res->layout-xlarge** => this will be for tablets

and also add in manifest

```
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
```

in support screens tag.

Answer (score 0):

see image below:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-p5bJpmwLhE4/TmtdTGyZnmI/AAAAAAAAADg/u06CDhu3x34/s1600/4.JPG

do that changes in your android manifest file.

also see below links it may help you.

http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-support-multiple-screens-in.html

one more thing remove this from your all activity declaration in manifest file

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

or

android:configChanges="orientation"

after above change generate new .APK file.

for more information see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html