# Android market not showing my apps in tablet

Tags: java, android, google-play

Recently i have posted my android app in to the market place. When search my app it shows and got installed in my Mobile but when search my app in Tablet its not showing the app. And i used to install directly from my account to Tablet its says that " 
This app is incompatible with your devices."

Any one help how can i made my app to show it in tablet to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add this to your manifest file -

```
<supports-screens  android:smallScreens="true"/>
<supports-screens  android:normalScreens="true"/>
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/>
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Just read out [Android Developer's Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for supporting multiple screensize application. Refer the existing [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10328374/940096) also

Answer (score 1):

```
" This app is incompatible with your devices."
```

It is because may be application feature(Screen size *just like @SpK said*, Bluetooth, 3g, Gps, EDGE, NFC) will not going to support your Tablet(Manifest declaration).

If you still want to download non-compatible application give a try http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-install-incompatible-apps-from-android-market-for-unsupported-devices/

Answer (score 1):

what does your manifest look like ? Please [read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html), it explains how the market (Google Play) filters apps based on what they declare in their manifest.

Chances are you forgot to add :

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

to your manifest.

But did you provide a tablet version of your app, with a proper UI design adapted for those devices ? This is an important question if you want to see users adopting your app on those devices...

Answer (score 1):

"This app is incompatible with your devices" could mean a few things as all the comments above are correct and yes I have published Tablet apps to the market and received the same response. Question

1: what "API LEVEL" have you defined in your manifest? 
2: what "What API Level" is the device?

I ask these 2 important questions because the only time I receive that comment from the Market is when I search for a app which api level is higher than my device. By default if your using Eclipse on Windows OS and your sdk is up to date the default api level will be set at 15 while the device your using to download the application to may be a api 7 -14.  If you have already followed all of the steps defined above by the other group members you should look into your manifest and see what uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion the app was developed on then compare that to the api level of your device and I assure you you will find that your app was developed on a api level higher than that of your device.