# When designing for tablets what should be the res folder structure?

Tags: android, android-layout, database-design

I am trying to make an application for tablet only . 
Can any one specify what should be the exact folder structure of res (resource folder ) for tablets

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453982/multiple-screen-support-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In all my tablet apps this is the structure I have, a drawable folder for xml created drawables,nine patch etc Then I have images for both Landscape and Potrait all meeting the ldpi,mdpi and hdpi. So the res folder has the following

drawable

drawable-land-ldpi
drawable-land-mdpi
drawable-land-hdpi

drawable-port-ldpi
drawable-port-mdpi
drawable-port-hdpi

Comment: what about layout folder structure ?

Comment: The layout folder remains as is nothing fancy to it. Android will automatically pick the relevant image from the drawables folder based on screen size,orientation, density etc. You do not have write multiple layout files to cater for the change in drawable size.