# How to create 720x1280 resolution layout in android

Tags: android, layout, size, resolution

I have an application with some edit texts and button. I have tried different screen support of this app by creating layout folders with resolution.
eg:res/layout-320x240/main.xml
There are different resolutions in res folder. Everything is ok. But I have a problem with 720x1280 resolution. I have an emulator with 720x1280, 320dpi emulator. While checking on this device I have getting output like this

[image: screenshot]

This is the actual view.

[image]

How can I fix this problem. All other resolutions are ok. Automatically detects screen size with emulator. Please give a solution..

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/book_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relative1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:hint="  Enter your source..."

    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect" />    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="BOOK YOUR JOURNEY"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="Contact:"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="From:"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="To:"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="Date:"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDate"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:textColor="#000000" >

</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  Enter your destination..."
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect" >


</AutoCompleteTextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editDate"
    android:text="Time:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTime"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editDate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:hint="  Time" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:hint="  Enter your name... " />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_name"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="  Enter your number..." >


    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Vehicle:"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_style" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="Passengers:"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
        android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_btnstyle"
        android:text="Exit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_btnstyle"
        android:text="Send" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have u create multipal layout folder in your project..........

Comment: @DanialHussain xml added with question

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar There is a main layout folder and other layout folders with resolution

Comment: have u create res/layout-large/

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar No. Created layout-600x1024/ layout-480x854/ layout-720x1280 etc..

Comment: so have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124079/supporting-multiple-screen-size-android

Comment: this is all because you are hardcoding the width and height of layout and other user interface components.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read google document for more detail.
Here is the Link [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screensize
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in   landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Thats code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **Linear Layout** with **orientation** vertical and orientation horizontal

The example code to provide weight rather than hardcoding

```
<Label
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Name :" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

you can take reference from developers.android.com [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Comment: "Linear Layout with orientation vertical and orientation horizontal" This makes no sense. Using weight is also a strange idea.