# How can i support multiple screen sizes in android with single xml layout file

Tags: android, xml

I want to support my android screen in multiple screen sizes but i can do it with maintaining multiple xml layout file's

but according to requirement it i supposed to be done with the single XML layout in order to optimize the app usage.

so please can you help me 
i have gone through multiple tutorials multiple links but not able to get last option with stack overflow

Comment: i dont think that there is any other solution because multiple xmls are intended for that purpose only. perhaps you can try it by aligning views relative to its parent and siblings or by giving proper weight to views so that they will acquire space on display proportional to the weight withing the parent layout.

Comment: The alternate resources you provide can vary depending on your use case. You might not need multiple layouts, you might just need alternate dimensions (for example). Also, I don't think it's worth being concerned about having additional layout files. There is usually some threshold (usually based on screen size) where you want an alternate layout, and that's usually enough (so 2 layouts--not unreasonable at all). Additionally, layouts are XML, which are highly compressible and take a tiny amount of space compared to things like images.

Answer (score 21):

**drawable:**

For images, you have to manage different drawable folders as per screen resolution:

```
drawable-ldpi        //240x320
drawable-mdpi        //320x480
drawable-hdpi        //480x800
drawable-xhdpi       //720x1280
drawable-xxhdpi      //1080X1920
drawable-xxxhdpi     //1440X2560
drawable-tvdpi       // nexus 7 etc 
drawable-xlarge-xhdpi //tablet like nexus 10
```

**dimes:**
For dimens, If you are using different static dimes as per your UI then you have to define them respected to their values... folders.

Values folder for different smart phones resolutions:

```
values-ldpi\dimens.xml
values-mdpi\dimens.xml
values-hdpi\dimens.xml
values-xhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxxhdpi\dimens.xml
```

Note: If you are using sp/sip/dp/dip then these values will be adjusted based on the density of device.
e.g Suppose you had set 10sp for TextView in mdpi(320X480) resolution device. Then this same value will be auto adjusted for other resolutions.

```
mdpi(10sp==10px)
hdpi(15px)
xhdpi(20px)
xxhdpi(30px)
xxxhdpi(40px)
```

These are the some general usage values folder which are used to manage dimens related to their screen resolutions.

**Different values folder for different screens:**

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xxxhdpi                 1440X2560 xxxhdpi

values-xxhdpi                  1080X1920 xxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

For knowledge in depth go with [Support screen resolution](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Answer (score 7):

Create three different `Layouts Folder` in your `res` folder for all devices and use the dimensions accordingly.

**Generic Layout Folders**

```
res/layout-small
res/layout-normal
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
```

After you are done with making your Normal/Medium Layouts follow these steps:

1. Convert the Normal Dimensions for other Screen Sizes.
2. Copy your Normal Layout xml files in to other Folders.
3. Change the suffix of the dimensions used according to the folder that you are in
4. Resize the Image Resources in your drawable folder (Width and Height - Same technique as we used for converting the dimens) and put them in their respective drawable folder (drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xdpi and so on).
5. Then your Layouts should work on every device with correct positioning.

**For converting Values**

```
0.75 - ldpi  (small)   //mdpi dimens *0.75
1.0  - mdpi  (normal)  //First create these dimensions
1.5  - hdpi  (large)   //mdpi dimens *1.5
2.0  - xhdpi (xLarge)  //mdpi dimens *2.0
```

**For Example**

```
android:layout_width="66dip" //in normal
android:layout_width="100dip"//in large 66*1.5=100(approx)
android:layout_width="52dip" //in small 66*0.75=52(approx)
```

Also new Qualifier has been introduced
 - SmallestWidth
 - AvailableScreenWidth
 - AvailableScreenHeight

read more about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try below library which manages all the screen size resolution automatically.

```
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

You need to just add the dependency in your build.gradle file and you are done.

You need to specify like:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
```

Instead of usual:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/10dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you provide text size as sp and other dimensions as dp. Android will automatically adjust for different layouts based on density of devices. If you want to control the values, you can put values in dimens.xml in each of values folders. The values folder inside res for different density devices will be following :

```
values-ldpi\dimens.xml
values-mdpi\dimens.xml
values-hdpi\dimens.xml
values-xhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxxhdpi\dimens.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends on your code

1. Dont use Static values
2. Try to use Wrap content
3. Use Relative and Linear Layout Depends on your Requirement
4. For `Drawables` Use every `DPI` Folder

**Look at these Links**

1)https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

2)[How to support different screen size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android)

3)[Supporting multiple screen size - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124079/supporting-multiple-screen-size-android)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

```
   <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                      android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                      android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this :

1) Put your images and icon in different `drawable` folder including `drawable-mdpi` , `drawable-hdpi` , `drawable-xhdpi` , `drawable-xxhdpi` , `drawable-xxxhdpi` which will be access image from particular folder based on screen resolutions.  Don't apply fixed values everywhere for image. Fixed dimensions can be vary with different device and image will be looked stretch. So use  **wrap_content**

2) Set dimensions in `dimens.xml` for different `values` folder.

```
values-mdpi\dimens.xml
values-hdpi\dimens.xml
values-xhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxxhdpi\dimens.xml
```

3) Use `LinearLayout` with proper using of `android:layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multi dimen files, and add dimensions of each view according to screen size in there.
You can find detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861248/2784838)

A set of six generalized densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi    (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Here is the [official](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) docs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use single layout and that should support all the screens like ldpi, , mdpi, hdpi, x-hdpi, xx-hdpi then you have to use weight in your layout that will handle screen size for all the screens.

Here’re a few things:

```
If you want to divide the space equally between Views with the same weight – set 0dp as Views’ width.
If you set View width to wrap_content – size of the Views will depend on weight and content inside each View.
```