# How to arrange dimens.xml for different screen resolutions?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I have 2 test devices namely, Oneplus 3T and Samsung S9. I have created dimens.xml in xxhdpi folder (intended for Oneplus 3T) and xxxhdpi folder (intended for Samsung S9). Frankly, Both devices use dimens.xml from xxhdpi instead. I have tried change the folder into sw400dp-xxhdpi and sw420dp-xxhdpi but still both devices take dimensions from xxhdpi folder instead.

How should I arrange my dimens.xml files such that different dimensions are applied separately for each respective device.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to remove my xxhdpi folder and define dimens.xml for Oneplus 3T inside folder values-sw360dp NOT values-sw400dp even though specs says that it has 401 ppi. values-sw400dp doesn't work for S9.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that S9 has 3 choices of display resolution namely, hd, fhd and wqhd. xhdpi works for hd, xxhdpi works for fhd and xxhdpi works for wqhd. Unfortunately, in debug mode, I cannot see the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606125/how-can-i-support-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android-with-single-xml-layout-file

Comment: @BolBazarMarme you can use ssp and sdp library for that https://github.com/intuit/sdp https://github.com/intuit/ssp or you can check its resource files for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create multiple dimens.xml file for this case.

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

[Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)

Comment: did you read my question or not? I did create multiple dimens.xml but both devices still use the same file namely xxhdpi/dimens.xml

Comment: otherwise you do have a library https://github.com/intuit/sdp