# Android drawable changing according to device screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to design below UI. To achieve same, i tried with drawables. 
**But issue is** : drawable showing differently on different screen sizes.
**For screen size 6.0 : drawables coming Oval and in below :  coming circle.**

**UI Design try to acheive:**

[image]

**content_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mediaagility.drawablesample.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/linear">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linear">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linear">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**linear_layout drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="2"
android:useLevel="false">


    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#FFB300" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"
        />
    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />
    </shape>
```

**bg_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="#1c75d1"
        android:gradientRadius="20dp"
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#609ede" />


    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />
</shape>
```

**main.class:**

```
 LinearLayout linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        LinearLayout linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
        LinearLayout linear3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear3);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        layoutParams.width = ApplicationUtils.getScreenWidth(this) / 4 +50;
        layoutParams.height = ApplicationUtils.getScreenWidth(this) / 4 +50;
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        layoutParams.leftMargin = ApplicationUtils.dpToPx(4);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = ApplicationUtils.dpToPx(4);

        linear1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linear2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linear3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**`Please help me by suggesting how to design below UI which independent on screen size.`**

Comment: post screenshot of your output!

Comment: Why are you adding those code under Main.class? **ApplicationUtils.getScreenWidth** is leading your UI change. I don't see any point in having those.

Comment: @SanjogShrestha  i added this to get circle size according to screen size but if i don't do this and set ui completely on drawables than it still changing o screen size

Comment: @KishoreJethava below is link showing output : https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqxidh9aozom8te/IMG_1100.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Used this library:-https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting fix size in `LinearLayout` thats why it stretched.
Remove it if not required.

your `xml` look proper you need work out at here

```
layoutParams.width = ApplicationUtils.getScreenWidth(this) / 4 +50;
layoutParams.height = ApplicationUtils.getScreenWidth(this) / 4 +50;
```

If you want support multiple screen with **fix size** then you should use **dimens.xml** for different dpi folder

- values-sw320dp-hdpi
- values-sw320dp-mdpi
- values-sw320dp-xhdpi
- values-sw320dp-xxhdpi
- values-sw320dp-xxxhdpi

this answers will guide you how to use `dimens.xml`. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124079/supporting-multiple-screen-size-android)

Comment: if i remove 50 than my 3 circles comes very congested. How to handle it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Information really helped. Please upvote question if u feel like. Thanks again :) .

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple background drawable, try using this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="4dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now set background to **TextView** as:

```
android:layout_width="your_width"
android:layout_height="your_height"    
android:background="@drawable/drawable_name"
```

This way, you don't have to look for **LinearLayout**.

Comment: If u see the UI pic,...there is an space between outer and inner circle. How would i able to achieve that in single drawable?

Comment: I play around with your code. And it really helped.

Comment: Glad it had helped you! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way to import drawables to your project is to use [drawable importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer). This solves the problem with the size of the images in different devices with different screen sizes.