# Android Landscape layouts

Tags: android, landscape

I got a problem fixing landscape layouts for my APP.

I got my app working completely only the background is screwed up when i view the app in landscape.
So i thought let me make a landscape layout.

I just copied the layout make and put -land behind the name, now i gain a error:

invalid resource directory name layout-hdpi-land    /Post NL Track Trace/res    line 1  Android AAPT Problem

Any solution

Comment: try using layout-land-hdpi ,densities should be mentioned after orientation i think.

Comment: I think you'll get help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558534/do-i-need-14-different-layouts-to-support-all-android-devices

Answer (score 1):

You are using worng convention. You should do this

> layout-land-hdpi

For details please read

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Well i tried that, but it did not work. No errors but also no difference in the layout