# Android Application Compatibility

Tags: android, android-manifest, compatibility

What should I have to write in manifest for android application screen compatibility for multiple android devices?
I tried compatible and support screen but its taking only normal layout.

Comment: we can put in layout side

Comment: By default, an android app will run on any device that is greater than or equal to the minSdkVersion.  Is it not running at all on the other device?  Or is it looking different than you expect?  And if so, what did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan: I wrote the separate layout for each xml according the corresponding density but still it's running according to layout-normal.I mean Xhdpi have to take layout-xlarge but it's taking layout-normal xml.What should I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

**But Seriously By giving this you can not achieve what you are looking for**

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) from developer site

also an [example](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Comment: @vinay see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558534/do-i-need-14-different-layouts-to-support-all-android-devices

Comment: Hey I wrote the separate layout for each xml according the corresponding density but still it's running according to layout-normal.I mean Xhdpi have to take layout-xlarge but it's taking layout-normal xml.What should I have to do?