# why my sign up page not coming same as all the mobiles in android?

Tags: imageview, android-edittext, android, android-resolution

My actual task is to design a sign up page is like this.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obTXdXMm4yZmRkUDQ/edit?usp=sharing

I did some coding that is

```
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/detailstenter"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="370"
            android:weightSum="122">


                             <EditText
                                 android:id="@+id/emailidenter"
                                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                 android:hint="john@clite.com"
                                 android:singleLine="true"
                                 android:ellipsize="end"

                                 android:background="@drawable/email_up"
                                 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usericon_two"
                                 android:textColor="#000000"
                                 android:textStyle="bold" >

                                 <requestFocus />
                             </EditText>
                                 <EditText
                                 android:id="@+id/password"
                                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:hint=".........."
                                 android:inputType="textPassword"
                                 android:singleLine="true"
                                 android:ellipsize="end"
                                 android:background="@drawable/email_down"
                                 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usericon_two"
                                 android:textColor="#000000"
                                 android:textStyle="bold" >

                                 <requestFocus />
                             </EditText>



                  </LinearLayout>
```

But when i running in the nexus 7 the out is changed.
this is https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obT1JGSlBjMHZSbnM/edit?usp=sharing
so please give some suggestions how can i do that task to get the output same as all the mobiles and tablets.

I tried image view+edit text with that background. But that is also not coming properly.

Please give some idea to this task.

thank you

shankar
clite

Comment: This is Emulator screen shots https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obNlF0TTBzZGNQSVE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ClitAndroid once use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: No man, By using relative layout also i didn't get. Can i get any links for design of this type of ui?

Comment: ok check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065701/applying-resolution-for-different-devices/19065842#19065842