# can i post 2 apk to google play pretending they are one application?

Tags: android, google-play

I need to make an application which have quite different design and some extra functionality for android phone and tablet.
Can i make separate .apk for phone and tablet and upload them as one or I need to make one .apk which has separate layouts and permission checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible. Please have a look at the respective article in the Android Developer Guide:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

However, Google encourages to develop and deploy only one APK for all devices for several reasons: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SingleAPK

Answer (score 1):

you need to make `one .apk`,because having two different .apk `just differing on the  basis of their compatible devices` will be kind of weird.You need to create your layouts according to the devices you want to run your app on,either for tablets or smartphones of different sizes.See this one [Do I need 14 different layouts to support all Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558534/do-i-need-14-different-layouts-to-support-all-android-devices)